# XGBoost unreasonable splitting value in nodes

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, xgboost

My xgboost model trained for a regression task in python using the xgboost package version 0.6 is using strange values for splits. Some values used as a splitting criteria are not present in the training dataset at all.
Example:
- there's a variable 'text' with values in the train set of [Missing,1,2]
- yet, a derived splitting criteria of a node in the trained model is '**text < 4**'

What could be a possible reason of such a split when no such value (-> 4) can be found in the data set?The split does not increase the information gain, since all samples follow one branch after this decision node.

Comment: Edit 1: It traces back to how xgboost handles the missing values for both dense and sparse format. In case of sparse format, missing values are put on one side of that split which maximizes the gain. Hence the reason of having all missing value at false side of 'text < 4' . By defaults, xgboost checks 'less than' split hence all train values of 'text' are less than 4 which will result in putting missing values to false side. Although more research is needed to check if Python Xgboost 0.6 implementation has this logic of also testing out of possible-set values as 'text' was never greater than 2

Answer (score 2):

A possible explanation: you have all non-missing values going to the 'text < 4' branch, and all missing values to the other - 'text > 4' - branch. Can you verify?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I followed the lead and found out that:

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I followed the lead and came to the conclusion that: 1- All missing values were going to one direction ('text > 4'). 2- Secondly, The same behavior was replicated by putting missing=0 for Dense DataFrame DMatrix conversion.  Now I am searching for a way to take advantage of Xgboost Sparse data handling (with most of sparse data set as 0 initially). Any further suggestions on how to make Xgboost work in sparse format for missing values?